# Why are the top two containers different sizes?

Tags: css, xhtml

The top two containers, containing the picture of beds are of unequal heights but I have set the width and height to be the same.

http://justbedroomdesigns.com/

Sorry to ask but I have no clue why they aren't the same height?

Edit: confusion in my questions seems apparent. I mean the top two that are side by side, not the two that are in the first column.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your CSS file

```
#title {
float: left;
idth: 410px;
}
```

should be

```
#title {
float: left;
width: 410px;
}
```

Comment: this is width, the heights are different for the first two in the first row?

Comment: No, they are the same height.

Comment: wow that's awesome guys.. to me they look different. what would i do without this awesome community.. Love you all.

Comment: wow that's awesome guys.. to me they look different. what would i do without this awesome community.. Love you all.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you are using IDs on your page more than once. DON'T DO THAT. ID's are meant to be used once per page. Switch them to classes.

Second, ASSIGN A WIDTH / HEIGHT TO YOUR IMAGES WITH PIXELS. Otherwise you will have problems like this. I can see you are using Wordpress, and you can do so in the WYSIWYG on the back end. Percentages are going to be a bad idea if you aren't sure on the exact widths / heights of where the images are being placed.

Next, check how it looks across browsers, Firefox looks good, Chrome not so much. IE7 doesn't like much at all.

Ok. So besides that, a quick fix might be.

```
.post-block img { 
width:338px;
height:248px}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same height. The box on the left is partially obscured by the box below it.

Comment: really?? I'll add another post to test. thanks

Comment: wow that's awesome guys.. to me they look different. what would i do without this awesome community.. Love you all.

Comment: wow that's awesome guys.. to me they look different. what would i do without this awesome community.. Love you all.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?